# I need to get Image taken to ImageView

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I took a picture from custom camera  but I cant display the photo taken in the new activity.
Here is my code byt its not working.
What is wrong?

```
    public class PicturePreview extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_preview);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photopreview);
    File imgFile = new  File(path);

    if(imgFile.exists()){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }


}

}
```

And here is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="involved.dreamon.PicturePreview">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photopreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you log the image path ? did you add image name with the image path ?

Comment: I did this in the CameraActivity

        ibUse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String path = "getPath";
                // Everything is saved so we can quit the app.
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PicturePreview.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("ImagePath", path);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

Comment: i don't talk about your listener . i told you to log the `String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath");` that, what's the value you are getting .

Comment: i'm not seeing any image name with the `path`

Comment: Im sorry mr Zahidul but Im new at development.. What should I write? And where?

Comment: do you know how to `Debug` or `Log` ?

Comment: Learn first -> https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Now check the value of `String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath");` value .

Comment: Follow the link i've gave you before .

Comment: You mean to write a log to see whats wrong?

Comment: Yes, Log the value and share it here .

Comment: Ok wait.. I will try...

Comment: Just write like this after  String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath"); Log.e("Path of Image is ", path); and see what it print in LogCat after reach on PicturePreview activity. got it

Comment: E/Path of Image is: ImgPath

Comment: Can someone guide me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

What king of exception do you have..not clear. If there is no problem but not showing image. Then image need to compress to set it in ImageView.

Some times it don't show when image regulation very high

use this method to solve this

```
public Bitmap imageConversion(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    Bitmap bitmap = imageBitmap;
    float lengthbmp = bitmap.getHeight();
    float widthbmp = bitmap.getWidth();
    if (lengthbmp > 1000) {
        if (widthbmp > 800) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, 800, true);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) widthbmp, 800,
                    true);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

use the method like this

```
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    image.setImageBitmap(imageConversion(myBitmap));

}
```